# Extracting ASP.NET Core diagnostics response time into a sematic logging database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging

I am using the default Visual Studio project template for C# WebApi using ASP.NET Core 3.1. When I start up the application, I see that the following information is logged on the console

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint 'webapi.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.Get (webapi)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 0.8083ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
```

As you can see, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics` is already logging the `response time` and the `http status code`, however its all part of the `log message` making it difficult to log those as specific searchable attributes into our elastic search database.

Is there any way to extract these information (response time & status code) from existing diagnostics middleware, without having to write our own?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is, take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/logging-tracing
One of the eventsources should have what you need. The information is somewhat scattered but its doable.

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to the individual attributes of a console log message by creating a custom console formatter, which is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/console-log-formatter#implement-a-custom-formatter).

Your custom formatter will subclass [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.ConsoleFormatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.console.consoleformatter) and override its [Write](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.console.consoleformatter.write) method.

The **logEntry** parameter of the **Write** method is what gives you access to the log message attributes.

An example of that can be found in the built-in [JsonConsoleFormatter](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/c81e83ab01fb3aed44de34e5aff659d28e6c91f4/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/src/JsonConsoleFormatter.cs#L65).

To give an example of how trivial this is to do (I still recommend referring to the examples I cited above to build something more robust), here's a complete top-level console app that implements a custom logger.  You'll just need to add a **Microsoft.AspNetCore.App** FrameworkReference to the project (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70847316)), then run it and make a request to *http://localhost:5000/notfound* to see it in action.

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
builder.Logging.AddConsole(consoleLoggerOptions => consoleLoggerOptions.FormatterName = nameof(CustomFormatter))
               .AddConsoleFormatter<CustomFormatter, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.ConsoleFormatterOptions>();
builder.Build().Run();

sealed class CustomFormatter : Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.ConsoleFormatter
{
    public CustomFormatter() : base(nameof(CustomFormatter))
    {
    }
    public override void Write<TState>(in LogEntry<TState> logEntry, IExternalScopeProvider? scopeProvider, TextWriter textWriter)
    {
        textWriter.WriteLine(logEntry.State);
        if ((logEntry.State is IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>> stateCollection))
        {
            Func<string, object?> getValue = key => stateCollection.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Key == key).Value;
            if (logEntry.Category == @"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics")
            {
                var statusCode = getValue("StatusCode");
                if (statusCode is not null) // this is a "Request finished" message
                {
                    var elapsedMilliseconds = getValue("ElapsedMilliseconds");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                    Console.WriteLine($"response time: {elapsedMilliseconds}ms  http status code: {statusCode}");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```