# How to reference ASP.NET Core 6 types in .NET 6 library?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, package, libraries

I am working on internal libraries for my organization. I need to reference certain types that normally "belong" to web apps, eg. to provide some extensions:

- `WebApplicationOptions`
- `HttpContext`

If I use `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`, i don't have references to these types and can't find any nuget package which contains them. If i use `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`, i can't build my class library because it is treated as application and has to specify entry point.

So, my question in general: **what is the right way to write libraries for ASP.NET Core 6?**

Back in core 2.x days there were packages for everything, like `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions`. They are all stuck at version `2.2.0` and i assume they're not usable now?

Comment: A very similar Q&A, differing mainly in the versions, but still after the huge change in ASP.NET Core 3.0: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58175530/2157640

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You need to add a `FrameworkReference` to your project file instead of a `PackageReference` as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework).

```
<ItemGroup>
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Right-click your project in the Solution Explorer and select "Edit Project File" to open the file and look for the `<ItemGroup>` section, creating a new one if it does not exist.

Comment: Just a side-note. Of course this does not work for `netstandard` targets.