# How to access the HttpContext in .Net 7 (as IHttpContextAccessor is deprecated)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0

I need to access the HttpContext from a custom component in a Asp.net Core WebApi app, and I found this page (under the point **'Access HttpContext from custom components'**):

https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/fundamentals/http-context.md

The above page suggests the usage of IHttpContextAccessor and **builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();** registration.

This page seems to be updated (5 months ago), but if i want to use the **IHttpContextAccessor** then i have to add a reference to the **Microsoft.AspnetCore.Http.Abstraction** package. And this package is **deprecated**. I couldn't find any alternative package for .Net7.

How can i accesss the HttpContext properly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70847263/how-to-reference-asp-net-core-6-types-in-net-6-library

Comment: In .NET 7 you can include the reference in this way `builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();`. You can get [`more details here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-7.0#access-httpcontext-from-custom-components)

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I'm developing a library and I have no builder/Services anywhere? Any other suggestion?

Comment: Would you kindly share your scenario and relevant code snippet so that it can be investigated accordingly.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I'm writing a library which override a method of a framework. Inside that overrided method, I need to get client IP address. That method is called by the framework, I can not modify the method input, hence, the easiest way is getting it from HttpContext. My project is just a class library so it has no Startup.cs or something similar to call `builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor()`

Comment: It would be nice if you could post new question, here in comment its very hard to explain.

Answer (score 9):

The IHttpContextAccessor is not deprecated, it is included in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` shared framework.

If your project is dependent upon this framework, it should work out-of-the-box.

If you use `Microsoft.NetCore.App` (which I suspect) you have to add a reference in your .csproj file

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework)